# Gutenberg - Prevent Column Nesting in the Visual Editor

Tags: block-editor

Hopefully someone can help me with this.

When a user adds a column layout in Gutenberg, I want to be able to prevent them from adding columns within columns - i.e. prevent nesting. So essentially, when they click to add a component in an already existing column, the Columns option doesn't appear, contrary to the screenshot below. N.B. I still want to be able to add columns at the initial level!

[image]

Is this possible?

Thanks